# How to dissolve or splice a list in common lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Let's say I have a function Foo that takes 3 arguments. Foo for example sums these 3 numbers.

```
(defun Foo (a b c) 
  (+ a b c)
```

Then I have have a list of these 3 values.
Is there a way of dissolving this list, so each value gets bind to the parameter?

```
(setf list (list 1 2 3))
> (1 2 3)
(Foo (dissolve list))
> 6
```

Only option I came up with was using macros, but then I got error such that ,@ cannot be right after backquote.

```
(defmacro dissolve (list)
  `,@list)
```

I know, one of the answers is to use &rest inside Foo function, but I don't want to. I am just wondering whether there is such a construct that fixes this from outside of the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is called [`apply`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm):

```
(apply #'+ '(1 2 3))
=> 6
```

What you are asking for, `(Foo (dissolve list))`, is impossible because of the evaluation rules of Lisp: `Foo` is a function and your form passes is exactly one argument.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I realized I could just call the function from the macro itself and that would solved the problem of ,@ being right after backquote.

```
(defmacro dissolve (func list)
  `(funcall ,func ,@list))
```

This answers the list dissolve at least in calling a function

Comment: Well, yes, except that `apply` does it better in every possible way. It is a function (so can itself be `appl`ied, passed around, etc), does not require the list to be known at compile-time (while your version does), has a more powerful syntax (takes a variable number of arguments, only the last one being a list, and "merges" all those with the last one as if by `list*`) and is in the standard so everybody knows what it does.

Comment: `(dissolve #'foo list)` will not work like `apply` because here `list` is a symbol named `"LIST"` when expanding code, not a literal list. Keep in mind macros work on code, there is no way for a macro to know what value `list` will hold when the code is executed (it could be an empty list, a list with one or two elements, etc.). You would need to generate code at runtime (for each different list) then evaluating that. That's usually not a good approach, especially when `apply` exists